# How to integrate nightwatch.js with WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, nightwatch.js

I am learning **nightwatch.js** for my current project. It seems that an IDE would be of great help and I am going to use **WebStorm**.

**My question is:** How to integrate *nightwatch.js* in *WebStorm* so that autocomplete features are available for writing tests.

Can anyone help me please?

Detailed steps will help me a lot.

Comment: As a long time Nightwatch user I can say webstorm, unfortunately, has always struggled with the intellisense (autocomplete) working correctly - especially if you command chain your test files. Still true at the time of writing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nightwatch wiki provides step by step process to integrate it with Webstorm IDE. This would help...
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Debugging-Nightwatch-tests-in-WebStorm

Comment: this only deals with setting up debug. How do you configure Webstorm to recognize nightwatch commands, be able to jump to them etc. for example i  have . client.perform(...) or client.oneOfMyCommands(...) how do i set up to recognize this?